# W3C Validators says my markup is invalid

Tags: xml, validation, rss

I've been running some tests through the W3C validator:

https://validator.w3.org/feed/check.cgi

All was going well until I decided to add an image using the "enclosure" element.

The validator stated that the image url was invalid, even though it was and was clickable.

I read through some posts and realised that many were experiencing the problem when running https, which I am. In order to prove/disprove this was the error I changed all the https: to http: but the error still persisted.

Eventually, I changed the image domain from a ".direct" to a ".com" and it validated. What the hell is going on? Surely not all feed validators are incapable of parsing any new domain name that has been launched in the last 5 years.

Anyone got any ideas as to how to get around this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><rss version="2.0"><channel xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"><title>This is a feed title</title><link>http://example.com/</link><description>This is a feed description</description><copyright>http://example.com 2016</copyright><lastBuildDate>Tue, 25 Oct 2016 16:08:07 +0100</lastBuildDate><atom:link href="http://example.com/feeds/myfeed" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" /><item><guid isPermaLink="true">http://example.com/</guid><link>http://example.com/</link><title>This is an item title</title><description>This is an item description</description><pubDate>Tue, 25 Oct 2016 00:00:00 Z</pubDate><enclosure type="image/jpeg" url="http://example.com/my-pic.jpg" length="2848" /></item></channel></rss>
```

Comment: It's worth noting that the FAQ for that page points to [a Google Code archive showing the last commit in 2010](https://code.google.com/archive/p/feedvalidator/source/default/commits). So yes, it's entirely possible this particular validator will reject any domain launched in the last 5 years.

Answer (score 0):

> Anyone got any ideas as to how to get around this?

There isn't anything to get around.

Validators are tools to help you with QA.

Sometimes tools have bugs. In this case, the URL validation code appears to have not been updated with the new rules for TLDs.

Either [report the bug](https://validator.w3.org/feed/about.html#when) and then ignore the error message until it gets fixed or [download the source code](https://validator.w3.org/feed/about.html#where) and fix the bug yourself (idealy offering a patch back to the community).